# In Bxslider continuous slider not working?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

In Bxslider , the slider stop on the certain slide run. Auto Callback not work.Please help!.

Here i have tried in the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slider1').bxSlider({
                infiniteLoop: true,
                auto: true,
                pager: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It works.

Try this,

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});
```

you can use additional options as per your requirement. if you don't want to show controls, you can hide it from CSS.

Comment: Are you adding images dynamically to the plug-in?

Comment: if it works for you, than pls accept the answer and upvote. this is how this community works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal', //mode: 'fade',  
        speed: 500,
        auto: true
    });
});
```